# object is being saved but the params are not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to make a simple blog app with rails as part of an exercise. Right now, you have the ability to add a comment on the post_path directly on show page of a post.

I'd like to be able to save a Comment object and have it be nested under a Post object so they are related.

My form looks like this:

```
#_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @comment, :url => post_comments_path(@post)  do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :content %>
  <%= f.text_field :content %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I click submit and I am transported to the comments controller:

```
  #comments_controller.rb
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.new
    @comment.save(comment_params) # @comment is saved but :content is nil
    if @comment.save(comment_params)
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end
  end
```

if I look at `comment_params` inside the create action I see:
`=> {"content"=>"asdfasdfasdfasdf"}`. The comment gets saved, however the :content portion is empty as you can see below:

```
=> #<Comment:0x007fd1da63ce60
 id: 4,
 content: nil,
 post_id: "1",
 created_at: Mon, 26 Oct 2015 21:45:22 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Mon, 26 Oct 2015 21:45:22 UTC +00:00,
 user_id: nil>
```

I do have `:content` white listed in my strong params:

```
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :post_id)
  end
```

Here are my models..

```
#post.rb

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :user
  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :body, :presence => true

  ###methods###
  def all_tags=(names)
    self.tags = names.split(",").map do |name|
        Tag.where(name: name.strip).first_or_create!
    end
  end
  def all_tags
    self.tags.map(&:name).join(", ")
  end

end

#comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

and my schema.

```
  # schema..
  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.string   "post_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "posts_tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "post_id"
    t.integer "tag_id"
  end

  create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "username"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing to:

```
#comments_controller.rb
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
end
```

Update with explanation:

old:

```
  # creates empty comment that belongs to @post
  @comment = @post.comments.new
```

new:

```
  #creates a comment that belongs to @post and has the content of comment_params
  @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
```

old:

```
  @comment.save(comment_params)
  if @comment.save(comment_params)
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
  # is the same as @comment.save({}) as far as save is concerned.  
  # save takes a hash for options.  It only uses the options it knows
  # So that is why it didn't complain.  It didn't find anything it knew 
  # in the hash comment_params.  So it just saved the empty comment
```

new:

```
  if @comment.save  # save the new comment that was generated with comment_params
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
```

Comment: Yes, that worked just fine. However, could you explain why my method was not working. I could understand if the entire thing broke but I find it weird that the `:user_id` was passed through but not anything else.

Comment: Your save was not working because you were creating an empty comment.  @comment.save does not know what to do with comment_params that you passed to it.  All it knows to do is save the object that is calling it which is an empty comment that belongs to post.  What We are doing now instead is creating a comment with comment_params instead of an empty comment.  Then we are calling save on that comment.